# How to run flutter app in background continually?

Tags: flutter

I try to run app in background to detect inclination of device.

To do this I ear that I need to use isolate. I test a code with isolate and add my logic to detect vertical angle. It's work but only 20seconds on my iphone.

How can I run a simple accelerometer continually in background ?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_isolate/flutter_isolate.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sensors/sensors.dart';


void isolate2(String arg) {
  getTemporaryDirectory().then((dir) {
    print("isolate2 temporary directory: $dir");
  });
  Timer.periodic(
      Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) => print("Timer Running From Isolate 2"));
}

void isolate1(String arg) async {
  /*final isolate =*/ await FlutterIsolate.spawn(isolate2, "text2");

  getTemporaryDirectory().then((dir) {
    print("isolate1 temporary directory: $dir");
  });
  Timer.periodic(
      Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) => print("Timer Running From Isolate 1"));
}

void main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {


  Future<void> _run() async {
    final isolate = await FlutterIsolate.spawn(isolate1, "text1");
    accelerometerEvents.listen((AccelerometerEvent event) {
      print(event.y);

      if (event.y>5.0||event.y<-5.0){
        print("vertical detection");

      }
    });

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Run'),
            onPressed: _run,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `workmanager` this helps us to perform background job

```
dependencies:
  workmanager: ^0.2.3
```

Two ways to perform background job

**1. Delayed background work**

registerOneOffTask runs the task only once with an initial delay of 10 seconds. This is useful when we need to perform any background work only once.

**Example:**

```
Workmanager.registerOneOffTask(
  "1",
  "registerOneOffTask",
  initialDelay: Duration(seconds: 10),
);
```

**2. Periodic background work**

This task runs periodically, Since we have not provided a frequency it will be the default 15 minutes.
**Example:**

```
Workmanager.registerPeriodicTask(
  "2",
  "registerPeriodicTask",
  initialDelay: Duration(seconds: 10),
);
```

Comment: Workmanager last update was in July 2020, and it support mostly Android. 
Maybe he can try https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch

Comment: I used it, it's working fine, for him, it should work for him as is a simple requirement.

Comment: Thank you, I tried but I have same comportment that isolate. consol display print only 20s after background. Perhaps it's work but I can monitor/verify I try to add vibrator() to test if my detection run in background but it work only when I'm not in background

Comment: Which mobile phone you are using?

Comment: sorry I need iOS and android, just see iOS isn't supported