# How to make a flutter app run in background?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, background-process

I am developing an app which uses an embedded system connected to through Bluetooth to an embedded device and I want the app to run a function when the device sends a signal.
The issue is that I cannot keep the app open all the time and thus need the app to keep running in the background and keep listening for the signal send by the embedded device so that it can run the function I want.
I have seen the following questions :

[How to run flutter app in background continually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66711189/how-to-run-flutter-app-in-background-continually)

[How can I make my flutter app run in background without stopping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72729769/how-can-i-make-my-flutter-app-run-in-background-without-stopping)

[How to create a service in Flutter to make an app to run always in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50106844/how-to-create-a-service-in-flutter-to-make-an-app-to-run-always-in-background)

and many more  and so far nothing seems to work.

I have written this code for now :

```
Future<void> _run_app_in_background() async {
    final config = FlutterBackgroundAndroidConfig(
      notificationTitle: 'MEDICA',
      notificationText:
      'MEDICA is  running in the background',
      notificationIcon: AndroidResource(name: 'background_icon'),
      notificationImportance: AndroidNotificationImportance.Default,
    );

    var hasPermissions = await FlutterBackground.hasPermissions;
    hasPermissions = await FlutterBackground.initialize(androidConfig: config);
    final backgroundExecution =
    await FlutterBackground.enableBackgroundExecution();
}
```

but it seems to be doing nothing and the same with other packages.

So how can I make my app run in background to keep listening for the Bluetooth data sent by device.

Edit:I want this to run on both Android and iOS and if possible maybe someone can suggest me another framework apart from Flutter (in comments maybe) and I can search the internet for the same.

Comment: PS : I am new to flutter , so I would appreciate if the answer can be kept at a basic/elementary level.

Comment: [https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes)

Comment: 1) It may help to review github issues for any plugin - https://github.com/JulianAssmann/flutter_background/issues and 2) On Android be aware of OEM background processing restrictions: https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Comment: @Chance I can't understand the article you linked , it seems to too advanced for my technical knowledge. However I have tried something it tells me to do and still nothing

Comment: @MorrisonChang I saw the github link and saw 2 issues which seem to be related to me (maybe?)
https://github.com/JulianAssmann/flutter_background/issues/57
https://github.com/JulianAssmann/flutter_background/issues/8

but I am still lost on how to solve these. Or maybe use some other package altogether?

Comment: Try with this package [link](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager)

Comment: The answer, on iOS (and, I suspect, on Android), is not to try to keep your app running. Rather, you need to use the facilities provided by the operating system for handling Bluetooth in the background. You need to add Bluetooth background mode capability to your iOS Xcode project and then activate notifications on the relevant characteristic. iOS will then deliver these data updates to your app in the background.

Comment: @Paulw11 that seems like what would help me, are you aware of any articles/guides that would help me for the same?

Comment: @Pothio I have tried that package but it  doesn't seem to work

Comment: I can't help you with Flutter. You may be able to find a flutter plug-in that can help you, but often with low level hardware type functionality you have to write platform specific native code.

Answer (score 0):

@HrishabhNayal Hello bro Try this way!

https://medium.com/dlt-labs-publication/flutter-run-code-in-the-background-461b4d6c635b

Comment: That article uses `background_fetch` which seems to execute the task only once in 15 mins at best. I cannot afford that as I need it as low as 1 sec.